# How to convert objectid to binary subtype 3 (uuid) with mongodb-erlang and bson-erlang?

Tags: mongodb, erlang, bson

I generate object ids like this: `mongodb_app:gen_objectid()`
This returns obviously a ObjectId type.

I need to have a BinType(3, ...) as we don't store objectids but binary subtype 3 ids.

Does anyone know how to convert this?

Comment: you can add your own answer here, and after 2 days you can even accept it - it's part of the SO way - and means people stop seeing this one as "unanswered" too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out how to fix it, I use the [uuid generator from avtobiff](https://github.com/avtobiff/erlang-uuid) for generating the UUID:

```
generate_objectid_subtype3() ->
    {bin, uuid, uuid:uuid4()}.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
%%This method is used to generate ObjectId from binary string.
binary_string_to_objectid(BinaryString) ->
    binary_string_to_objectid(BinaryString, []).

binary_string_to_objectid(<<>>, Result) ->
    {list_to_binary(lists:reverse(Result))};
binary_string_to_objectid(<<BS:2/binary, Bin/binary>>, Result) ->
    binary_string_to_objectid(Bin, [erlang:binary_to_integer(BS, 16)|Result]).

%%This method is used to generate binary string from objectid.
objectid_to_binary_string({Id}) ->
    objectid_to_binary_string(Id, []).

objectid_to_binary_string(<<>>, Result) ->
    list_to_binary(lists:reverse(Result));
objectid_to_binary_string(<<Hex:8, Bin/binary>>, Result) ->
    StringList1 = erlang:integer_to_list(Hex, 16),
    StringList2 = case erlang:length(StringList1) of
        1 ->
            ["0"|StringList1];
        _ ->
            StringList1
    end,
    objectid_to_binary_string(Bin, [StringList2|Result]).
```

Test Example:

    binary_string_to_objectid(<<"51F5BE99118735B187000001">>).
Out Put:
    {<<81,245,190,153,17,135,53,177,135,0,0,1>>}

    objectid_to_binary_string({<<81,245,190,153,17,135,53,177,135,0,0,1>>}).
Out Put:
<<"51F5BE99118735B187000001">>